# Forty people are given a new drug for the treatment of a disease... patients expected to be treated successfully?

Tags: probability

Forty people are given a new drug for the treatment of a disease. the success rate of this drug is  90%. how many of patients can be expected to be treated successfully?

is 36 the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 36 is correct. Let $X_i$ be the outcome of the drug on person $i$ ($1\leq i\leq 40$).

$$\begin{align}\Bbb E[\# \text{ of successes}]&=\sum_i\Bbb P(X_i=\text {success})\times 1
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{40}0.9\\&=36\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

All you do is multiply 0.90 by 40, and the you get 36, as said.